# Как использовать Metamask в selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Есть необходимость использовать крипто-кошелек "MetaMask" в проекте Selenium.
Но, при каждом запуске необходимо вводить фразу, можно как-то сохранить ее файлом чтоб в дальнейшем запускалось без неё

Вот текущий код:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common import by
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
url = ""
options.add_extension('test.crx')# расширение Metamask для браузера
s = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
browser = Chrome(service=s,chrome_options=options)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bselenium%5d%20cookies&searchOn=3)